# How to display form on the body after pressing submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to display form on the body. When each user presses submit button his information will be displayed on the top of body and previous form will go down it.
I want like this

```
                        ------------------  //First form
                       |name:Bill gates   |
                       |                  |
                       |Email:BG@email.com|
                       |                  |
                       |Address:etc       |
                        ------------------


                        ------------------  //Second form
                       |name:Bill gates   |
                       |                  |
                       |Email:BG@email.com|
                       |                  |
                       |Address:etc       |
                        ------------------

                        ------------------  //Third form
                       |name:Bill gates   |
                       |                  |
                       |Email:BG@email.com|
                       |                  |
                       |Address:etc       |
                        ------------------
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) ? Try Ajax post on submit event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could listen to 'submit' event:

```
$('form').on('submit', doSomething[function]);
```

then serialize the form with:

```
var params = $('form').serializeArray();
```

this will give a serialize an array with all the parameters coming from the form,
the with params you can do whatever you wish, you have the control.

If that doesn't answer your question, please provide me with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).